# get result of table 1 based on table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

my query is this :

```
SELECT
    id, 
    IF(allotment_type = 'Agent', COUNT(allotment_type), 0) AS total 
FROM vip_allotment 
WHERE
    (SELECT 
        date_from,
        date_to 
     FROM date_total 
     WHERE
        date_from >= '$date_1' 
        AND date_to <= '$date_2' )
```

I have a table named `vip_allotment` and I want the result to be based on date on another table named `date_total` , I want to make sure the `date_from is >= $variable and date_to <= $variable2` .

The main problem is that I can't get result of a `table1` based on `table2` .

NEW EDIT:

vip_allotment fiels is:

```
id
general_setting_id
ddate
timex
hotel_id
cr_by
emp_id
update_emp_id
notes
date_from
date_to
allotment_type
```

date_total table :

```
id
date_from
date_to
```

Comment: What fields are tables `vip_allotment` and `date_total` joining on? Can you show us table definitions and some sample data?

Comment: @Moseleyi i edited the post may it help

Comment: So are `date_from` and `date_to` a join between the tables? If yes then you don't need the `date_total` table, if it's a no, I'm not sure what are you applying the second table for?

Comment: what i use in query is allotment_type from vip_allotment and want it to based on date that in date_total table

Comment: @Moseleyi  apply the second table to make on it something like calender to help me use that calender as date based for another table to make me avoid gap between data on database

Comment: Show me sample data, because we still don't know the relation between `date_from` and `date_to` on `vip_allotment` and same columns on the other table

Comment: @Moseleyi thanks for replying , consider those two fields (date_from , date_to ) on table ( vip_allotment ) didn't exist , all i want is to use the fields in ( date_total ) as date based on , appreciate your patience

Comment: But in order to use it you need to establish a relationship between them, otherwise there will be like different statements. `WHERE` needs the field that is being checked and then the conditions. For example `WHERE ddate > date_from AND ddate < date_to` Without relationship you can't build such query

Comment: @Moseleyi the problem i face that i have many tables and i want them all to check their values ( condition ) with one table named date_total and in date_total i will put a range of dates just to make other tables make greater and smaller than those dates to arrange a report with all data , i know my english is bad but i wish you know what i mean , you can say i want to relation id with id .

Comment: I'll put an answer as an example, this is just my hunch, because I still don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but want to show you an example code, what I mean by relationship

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    id, 
    IF(allotment_type = 'Agent', COUNT(allotment_type), 0) AS total 
FROM vip_allotment va
    LEFT JOIN date_total dt ON dt.date_from >= '$date_1' AND dt.date_to <= '$date_2'
WHERE
    va.ddate >= dt.date_from
    AND va.ddate <= dt.date_to
```

As you can see the `WHERE` clause now contains a field `va.ddate` that is checked against the result of the join to find the  range from `date_total` based on the parameters.

It's far from perfect (you might get multiple results from `dt` for example) but just wanted to see if that's the right direction of what you're trying to do?